# Error while adding an Account in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, account

While adding iTunes account in Xcode, Receive "This action could not be completed.try again later. in Xcode preferences

Comment: This happens because Apple's servers may not be working correctly. Just wait and try later or next time. It will work for sure eventually.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. However... Double check if your credentials are working. If you can login the developer portal, you should be able to login in Xcode, or try again later, as the message says. If it still doesn't work, file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens due to error in network or sometime errors from apple server.
You can do following:

1. Try adding account by connecting to another network and make sure
   internet connection is working well.
2. If step 1 didn't work,
   remove the account from Xcode, kill the Xcode app and open again.
   Then add account again.

---